# Spring Security UI 0.2

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have decided to use spring security UI in my grails application.
It uses the Register layout but I want it to use my main layout.
When I change it the main layout I loose all the fancy looking login screen.

Is there a way I can use the css from my main aswell as the fancy look of the register layouts?

Also I have been searching the net and can not find any good documentation on customizing the Spring security UI

I am very new to creating web UI's in grails and any ideas on where to look would be great as I have a lot of "making stuff pretty" things to do.

FOR OTHERS LOOKING AT THIS I FOUND A VERY GOOD SITE TO HELP YOU UNDERSTAND
http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/grails-goodness-applying-layouts-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security UI uses the resource plugin to configure its apparency. It configures three 'modules' that you can use: `spring-security-ui`, `register` and `ajax-login` You need to include the modules in you gsp header, something like

```
<r:require modules="spring-security-ui"/>
```

Comment: The register module removes my css is there anything i do to change this?

Answer (score 1):

I open another answer because I cannot format my code in comment.

You can create your module and register it in your page or layer. Resource are created in grails-app/config directory. You create a file YourModuleResources.groovy and put your css in it. e.g:

```
modules = {
    mystyles {
        resource url: 'js/myjavascripts.js'
        resource url: 'css/mystyle1.css'
        resource url: 'css/mystyle2.css'
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```
<r:require modules="mystyles"/>
```

Comment: Please edit your original answer to add the new information rather than creating a new answer.